# Laravel new doesn't work in my local environment

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create a new laravel app, but when I use the command "laravel new" I've got an error :

```
laravel new
Crafting application...
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for phpunit/php-token-stream 2.0.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-token-stream[2.0.0].
    - phpunit/php-token-stream 2.0.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 2
    - phpunit/php-token-stream 2.0.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/php-code-coverage 4.0.8 requires phpunit/php-token-stream ^1.4.2 || ^2.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-token-stream[2.0.0].
    - Installation request for phpunit/php-code-coverage 4.0.8 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[4.0.8].

Application ready! Build something amazing.
```

I'm on Windows 10, with php 5.6.30 installed.

I already tried to update composer itself, and laravel's installer (via composer global require "laravel/installer"), but it still doesn't work.

Last time I tried on this computer was three weeks ago, and it worked then.

Edit : I can't change my PHP version since it is the one I use on my server.

Comment: The error states that you need php 7.0 or higher

Comment: Like @Jerodev said, one of the packages requires php 7.0 or higher

Comment: I think you should update your php to 7.0 version

Comment: But how come it worked before ? How can I install the latest (5.4) version of Laravel on a PHP 5.6 environment ?

Comment: try `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "5.4.*"` for installing laravel 5.4

Comment: update your php will solve the problem

Comment: @baig772 thanks for the constructive comment. Can you make it an answer so I can validate it ? @ all the others, I can't change my version since it's the same I've got on my production server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to download the latest realease of laravel. Though it is 5.4 but for some reason, it is downloading laravel's version that is compatible only with `PHP7`
Try with `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "5.4.*"` to install laravel 5.4

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! It also worked without telling the version number.

Answer (score 0):

It's only the phpunit version. Change the version to smaller, like:

`"phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7"`

to

`"phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0"`